# PHPUnit mock method used in another class

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, paypal, phpunit

PHPUnit mock method used in another class?
Example:

```
class Main {
  function makePayment() {
    $pp = new PayPalSOAPSomeClass();
    return $pp->doExpressCheckout();
  }
}
```

in testing i want test my Main class, and mock doExpressCheckout() method, my not worked code to test:

```
public function testStub()    {
        $stub = $this->getMock('PayPalSOAPSomeClass');
        $stub->expects($this->any())
             ->method('doExpressCheckout')
             ->will($this->returnValue(false));
        $pp = new Main;
        $this->assertEquals(true, $pp->doExpressCheckout());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem testing the Main class.  The first problem is that it creates an object internally.  You need to modify this class to use dependency injection.  Your makePayment()  should accept a PayPalSOAPSomeClass object.

```
function makePayment(PayPalSOAPSomeClass $pp)
{
    return $pp->doExpressCheckout();
}
```

In your main class, you can modify it to use a constructor dependency injection, or a setter dependency injection, which is better than the makePayment.  Then, you reference the internal object.

For instance:

```
class Main {
    private $svc;

    // Constructor Injection, pass the PayPalSOAPSomeClass object here
    public function __construct($Service = NULL)
    {
        if(! is_null($Service) )
        {
            if($Service instanceof PayPalSOAPSomeClass)
            {
                $this->SetPayPalSOAP($Service);
            }
        }
    }

    function SetPayPalSOAP(PayPalSOAPSomeClass $Service)
    {
        $this->svc = $Service;
    }

    function makePayment() {
        $pp = $this->svc;
        return $pp->doExpressCheckout();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public function testStub()    
{
    $stub = $this->getMock('PayPalSOAPSomeClass');
    $stub->expects($this->any())
        ->method('doExpressCheckout')
        ->will($this->returnValue(false));
    $pp = new Main($stub);
    $this->assertEquals(true, $pp->doExpressCheckout());
}
```

Comment: If i do like you say, for why i need mock? I can write something as $this->assertEquals(true, false); because in mock i set false return value

Comment: After DI, injected class has public properties, how i can set this properties?

Comment: Yes you can, and that works in a very limited scope.  Afterwards, you will want to test more thoroughly this code and have more complex returns, such as the responses, errors, etc...  Mocking allows your code to still call the proper internal functions, to ensure that the code behaves accordingly on returned data.  You can get reference numbers, and ensure they are right. Account balances, processing errors, etc...  All these may be returned by the mock, which your library code tests to ensure you module handles all the response correctly.